# if else vs math in mapping small sequences

Tags: python, c, performance, if-statement, mapping

I recently had to transform the sign of an integer into either -1 or 1

I wonder, is it faster to do it via an if else statement or by doing a calculation?

```
#if else#
s == -1 ? -1 : 1

#calculation#
ceil((s + 1) / 2) * 2 - 1
```

I know it's quite a simple example but sometimes you need to map larger intervals and, intuitively, it just seems that the math will be faster at lest for the smaller ones.

Also, how is the relative speed affected by the language used (eg. Python vs C).

Comment: The second solution does not work. Consider what happens if `s` is the biggest positive integer, then `s+1` overflows and you have undefined behaviour! So, between a working solution and a not-working one, choose the working one.

Comment: I was talking about mapping the range -1, 0, 1 to -1, -1, 1 (first line), sorry if it's vague

Comment: @AsoneTuhid: If I were you I'd add that mapping to the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

The `?` operator will be slightly faster because it involves less number of instructions and our days processors are often smart enough not to break the pipeline, although it should look this way:

```
int r = (s < 0) ? -1 : 1;
```

Parenthesis are for clarity.

In case if `s` can be only -1, 0 or 1, I would recommend:

```
int v[] = { -1, 1, 1 };
int r = v[s+1];
```

This will never break the CPU pipeline.

Comment: Considering that s can only have values of -1, 0 and 1, is it faster to use
    s < 0
or
    s == -1
?

Comment: Why did I not think of the array method? Have an upvote!

Comment: @AsoneTuhid, both relational expressions evaluate to either 0 or 1, the OP wants -1 or 1.

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that, would it be faster than if/else though?

Comment: Now the OP has provided the function, I think you need `s <= 0` and `{-1, -1, 1}` as the array.

Comment: @AsoneTuhid: There are very few things faster in life than looking up an element from an array. This is the best answer, IMHO.

Comment: @Bathsheba "There are very few things faster in life than looking up an element from an array."   even in python?

Comment: Sorry, i'll go eat some quiche in shame

Answer (score 1):

Modern compilers are not idiotic. They won't give silly unnecessary jumps for conditional moves, for example. (That's not to say they're smart, though.) Given `return x == -1 ? -1 : 1;`, Clang and GCC respectively produce

```
sgn:                                    # @sgn
    cmp     edi, -1
    mov     eax, 1
    cmove   eax, edi
    ret
```

and

```
sgn:
    xor     eax, eax
    cmp     edi, -1
    setne   al
    lea     eax, [rax-1+rax]
    ret
```

These are pretty good, but I'd expect a shift + `or` to be faster. `return (2 * -(x < 0)) + 1;` compiles to

```
sgn:                                    # @sgn
    sar     edi, 30
    or      edi, 1
    mov     eax, edi
    ret
```

and

```
sgn:
    mov     eax, edi
    sar     eax, 31
    or      eax, 1
    ret
```

respectively. These are pretty damn fast.

The same will not be true on CPython, since that's an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If performance *really* matters that much, I think it would be difficult to beat code that transforms {-1, 0, 1} to {-1, -1, 1} by

1. Subtracting 1.
2. Extracting the sign bit.

In C you could thump that out with a couple of inline assembly statements, depending on your platform.

That will probably beat the equivalent ternary conditional (actually `s <= 0 ? -1 : 1`) as an incorrect branch branch prediction will cause the CPU to dump the pipeline.

With a micro-optimisation like this you need to answer it with *profiling*, set up an adequate testing framework and measure the performance to an appropriate statistically significant level.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the boolean operator is >5 times faster than math:

```
%timeit (math.ceil((s + 1) / 2) * 2 - 1)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 381 ns per loop

%timeit (-1 if s < 0 else 1)
#10000000 loops, best of 3: 70.1 ns per loop
```

In Python, you can also use direct dictionary lookup, which is surprisingly almost as good as the boolean if:

```
d = {-1:-1, 0:-1, 1:1}
%timeit d[s]
#10000000 loops, best of 3: 73.8 ns per loop
```